# ionic2 application is to slow on android 4.4.2

Tags: android, typescript, ionic2

I had run my ionic2 application on android device version **4.4.2**.

> But the ionic2 application is to slow.

I had run the ionic2 application on android device version **5.0.1**.

> The ionic2 application is working well "**Fast**".

The ionic2 version is: **2.1.3**

The typescript version is: **2.3.4**

Any solution to make the ionic2 fast on the android **4.4.2**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's highly recommended to use [Crosswalk](https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview) on projects that target Android versions bellow 4.4.4.

Oficially Ionic supports any Android version from 4.4.1 and so on, but you can experience performance issues from that version to 4.4.4.

But be aware that using Crosswalk'll increase your app size by something about 20MB.

Comment: I would ask you if the ionic2 media plugin is compatible with crosswalk?